# Datatype DataAnnotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I'm reading on this on MSDN and it doesn't really describe much. It says that it is used to specify the data type to associate with a data column or a parameter. Makes sense. Does this mean I should use it on all of my properties? I assume not. So why is there a DataType.Text, seems pretty useless when you have a property as a string.

I've found a use for it to use multi-line text as a datatype to create a textarea on the client side instead of just a single line text input element. But how does this relate to a data column or paramater?

I also assumed that it would also validate it since I used DataType.Url but it goes through whether or not a Url is entered or not. Same with DataType.Email. Is there something I'm doing wrong or do I need to use a RegEx instead?

Comment: You want to use RegEx for what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See my MSDN article [DataType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype.aspx)
These are NOT validation attributes. From the MSDN article:

> The DataTypeAttribute attribute lets you mark fields by using a type
>   that is more specific than the database intrinsic types. For example,
>   a string data field that contains e-mail addresses can be attributed
>   with the EmailAddress type. This information can be accessed by the
>   field templates and modify how the data field is processed. (that is,
>   create a link)

Comment: Ok, for some reason I thought they could validate. I understand what you mean now with the email address link for the display and whatnot, makes sense. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: It seems that now they ARE validation attributes. In MVC 4 at least, DataTypeAttribute derives from ValidationAttribute.

Answer (score 5):

The `DataType` attribute in the context of ASP.NET MVC is more or less a hint of what view template to use for rendering a display and editor for that property. As you have noticed it provides an enumeration of supported data types for which ASP.NET MVC internally provides editor and display templates (MultilineText -> textarea html input), but it can also take a string parameter with a custom  type name. All that it does is look for a view with that name (pre-defined or not) in the `Views/ControllerName/EditorTemplates/{DataTypeName}.cshtml` or `Views/ControllerName/DisplayTemplates/{DataTypeName}.cshtml` when you use Editor/EditorFor or Display/DisplayFor accordingly (it will also search in Views/Shared/...). If it doesn't fine one it uses a built-in one if available.

The effect of applying a `DataType` attribute is pretty much the same as if applying the `UIHint` attribute, but it's a bit more explicit. For example I would use a `DataType.Currency` on a price and a UIHint on a - say - custom slider ui control model property.

Regarding validation - the build-in templates provide it, but if you were to use a custom datatype in your custom display/editor template you would have to provide that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The `DataTypeAttribute` don't validate anything despite of inheritance from `ValidationAttribute`. It overrides `IsValid()` method, but simply returns `true` always.

If you want to validate your `Email` or `Url` field, use `EmailAttribute` or `UrlAttribute` instead. These are inherited from `DataTypeAttribute` and override `IsValid()` method appropriately.

This is the whole list of specific DataType attributes:

- `CreditCardAttribute`
- `EmailAddressAttribute`
- `EnumDataTypeAttribute`
- `FileExtensionsAttribute`
- `PhoneAttribute`
- `UrlAttribute`

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're asking but the [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc490428%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) help you mark properties based on business needs (Like Email, Phone Number etc)

See the Members the [DataType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

What is this for?

When you annotate your classes and use them as models in your MVC app. asp.net-mvc will take care of validation (even on the client with javascript if you have everything in place)

See this tutorial for an example:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6